# dotnetnuke - How do I create a container skin so that its title is only shown in edit and layout modes?

Tags: dotnetnuke

How do I create a container skin so that its title is only shown in edit and layout modes?

I know I can set show-container: false in the page settings... but I'd really rather not have to set this for all pages on the entire site that my container skin is installed on.

Comment: So you only want the title of the module to show in the container when viewing as page editor? Does it matter to you if the action icons are shown? The rest of the container?

Comment: Currently, I have the Edit Content & Settings action buttons/links showing in edit mode and layout mode, but the module title shows in all 3 modes. So, to answer your question, I'd like the settings and edit content buttons/links to continue operating as they are, and the title to not display in view mode. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is DNN4, and I didn't write it, but here is the code ripped from our container that does just this. I will let you slog thru and decide which parts you don't need:

Here is the line from the container's ascx file...

```
<DNN:DNNToolBar id="tbEIPTitle" runat="server" CssClass="eipbackimg" ReuseToolbar="true">...
```

and code from the ascx.vb file...

```
 Private Function CanEditModule() As Boolean
     Dim blnCanEdit As Boolean = False
     Dim objModule As Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase = Container.GetPortalModuleBase(Me)
     If (Not objModule Is Nothing) AndAlso (objModule.ModuleId > Null.NullInteger) Then
         blnCanEdit = (PortalSettings.UserMode = PortalSettings.Mode.Edit) 
             AndAlso (PortalSecurity.IsInRoles(PortalSettings.AdministratorRoleName)
             OrElse PortalSecurity.IsInRoles(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.AdministratorRoles.ToString))
             AndAlso (IsAdminControl() = False) 
             AndAlso (PortalSettings.ActiveTab.IsAdminTab = False)
      End If
      Return blnCanEdit
 End Function
```

and...

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ...
    If CanEditModule() = False OrElse Entities.Portals.PortalSettings.GetSiteSetting(objPortalModule.PortalId, "InlineEditorEnabled") = "False" Then
        lblTitle.EditEnabled = False
        tbEIPTitle.Visible = False
        ....
```

Comment: Bill, so your container file has a code-behind file? Just want to confirm. Didn't know that was possible... but it makes sense

Comment: @hamlin - yes. our skin/container is a mess of ascx and ascx.vb files, although the code I sent was from \admin\containers, so it may be part of the standard DNN4 package.